# Como manter uma function Javascript na DOM mesmo depois de um page load de outra página?

Tags: javascript, dom

Até onde eu sei não é possível manter o estado da DOM mesmo depois do page load, existe alguma técnica ou alguma maneira fora manter a function em cookie ou storage(local, session) para posteriormente dar eval()?

Comment: Leandro, qual o propósito disso?

Comment: Seguinte, eu recebo de rest server um JSON criptografado e também o método javascript com uma chave única para decriptar o conteúdo do JSON, ao receber essa function armazeno ela na dom dando eval(). porém caso eu dê akgum page load perco tudo o que estava na DOM, preciso manter esse método vivo sem storage ou cookie, mas estou vendo que isso é impossível.

Comment: Porque você não salva apenas a chave para descriptografar o conteúdo?

Answer (score 3):

Não aconselho manter a informação numa *funcion*. Seria melhor modificar o código e armazenar somente as chaves necessárias.

Além disso, local storage não é recomendado para armazenar informações de sessão ou dados "sensíveis" ([fonte](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Local_Storage)).

Neste caso, seria mais adequada a utilização de um *cookie*. Se possível, use `HTTPS` e a *flag* [`secure`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly) ativada, o que ajuda a evitar alguns ataques do tipo *man-in-the-middle*. Como você precisa acessar a chave no JavaScript, não poderá acionar `httpOnly`, portanto sua página será suscetível a ataques XSS (*Cross-Site Scripting*).

Mas entenda que qualquer chave gravada no cliente não oferece bons níveis de segurança, dá quase no mesmo de usar um *session id* qualquer, afinal qualquer um que que consiga ter acesso às informações da sua página poderá replicar o comportamento "natural" do sistema.

Comment: Mas o seguinte a chave não é gerada pelo cleinte e sim pelo rest. Quando eu mando o objeto JSON do rest para o client eu já mando um método em javascript com uma chave única dentro do método exemplo:

function a (b){
var d = "4jn234324uh234u4h3";
return  decrypt(b,d);
}

Na próxima requisição seria
function a (b){
var d = "5fg4df564gdf65g4fg654f";
return  decrypt(b,d);
}

E consequentemente só o client poderia abrir o conteúdo do json visto que todo o token e toda a informação depende de chave que é dinâmica para cada requisição.

Comment: @LeandroCurioso Perfeitamente. Eu entendi isso. A única coisa que está torta na resposta é que você não poderá usar a flag `httpOnly` para acessar o cookie através do script. O problema disso é que seu site sempre será vulnerável a ataques XSS.

Comment: @LeandroCurioso Mas se é dinâmica para cada requisição, porque armazenar, então?

Comment: @LeandroCurioso Neste caso o que você tem é um *token*, que serve contra ataques [CRSF (Cross-site request forgery)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: O problema está no page load visto que recebo o método e dou eval(); Dentro da propria chamada do cliente para o serviço, porém quando o mesmo muda de página eu não tenho mais o método eu teria que salvar ele em cookie e storage que é o que não quero.

Comment: @LeandroCurioso O correto é se mudar de página o servidor enviar outra função e não usar a anterior. Caso contrário vai virar gambiarra. Todas as soluções de CRSF funcionam dessa forma.

Comment: Mas ai fica a pergunta.tudo bem mas como a chamada do cliente para o rest irá receber um cookie visto que envio objeto para o rest e só recebo objetos JSON. Como posso setar um cookie http only pelo rest para cada client?

Comment: @LeandroCurioso Neste caso, a página carregada precisa vir com uma chave embutida e as demais requisições REST podem retornar a próxima chave normalmente. Porém, não sei se não estou entendendo bem, mas me parece haver um problema. O que acontece se uma das chamadas REST falhar? Imagine o caso da conexão com a internet do usuário oscilar. Esse procedimento me parece que vai causar mais problemas do que solucionar.

Comment: se a conexão falhar, uso try catch e na exceção mando o cliente para página de erro interno, login ou algo do tipo

Comment: A arquitetura está funcionando bem desde a geração da chave, a criação do metodo JS e o eval(); Porém no page load da outra página perco tudo que tinha no eval(); e por mais que tenha um hash em cookie não tenho mais o método para decrytar

Comment: Talvez se eu gerar outro token apenas para que no page load de cada página possa requisitar o javascript necessário para o descrytar o conteúdo.

Comment: @LeandroCurioso Exato. Esse é o modo correto.